# Building chainable filter components in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, react-hooks, react-component

What's the most "React"y way to build reusable, chainable filter components?

Let's say I have an input array:

```
[
{name: 'Generic t-shirt', size: 'xxl', available: 35},
{name: 'Generic t-shirt', size: 'md', available: 2},
{name: 'Generic t-shirt', size: 'sm', available: 5},
{name: 'Really awesome shirt', size: 'md', available: 0}
]
```

And a keyword search for the name, a dropdown for size, and a "sold out" boolean checkbox for availability.

Right now, I have the filtering code inside the rendering loop:

```
const [productsFilteredByFullText, setProductsFilteredByFullText] = useState;
const [productsFilteredBySize, setProductsFilteredBySize] = useState;
const [productsFilteredByAvailability, setProductsFilteredByAvailability] = useState;

const searchResults = useMemo(() => {
    let filteredProducts = eventsFromAPI; // array of products as input

    filteredProducts = filteredEvents.filter(product => fullTextFilter(product));
    filteredProducts = filteredEvents.filter(product => sizeFilter(product));
    filteredProducts = filteredEvents.filter(product => availabilityFilter(product));

    return filteredProducts;
}, [productsFilteredByFullText, productsFilteredBySize, productsFilteredByAvailability]);
```

And the UI inside JSX:

```
<div>

    // Fulltext search
    <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Keyword search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={fullTextHandler}
    />


    // Size dropdown
    <Dropdown
        options={allAvailableSizes}
        onChange={sizeHandler}
    />

    // Sold out checkbox
    <input
        name="soldout"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={productsFilteredByAvailability}
        onChange={availabilityHandler}
    />

    <h1>Results</h1>
    {filteredProducts.map(item => (
        <Product item={item} />
    ))}
</div>
```

This works, but is not very reusable at all. Let's say I have another product category, scarves, that are all one size, but I still want to be able to re-use the filter component and logic for name and availability.

Is there a way to modularize/componentize BOTH the filter logic AND the presentation JSX into separate filter components, and be able to chain them together arbitrarily? Something like this pseuocode:

```
<TShirtList>
<NameFilter/>
<SizeFilter/>
<AvailabilityFilter/>
</TShirtList>

<ScarfList>
<NameFilter/>
<AvailabilityFilter/>
</ScarfList>

<ServicesList>
<NameFilter/>
</ServicesList>
```

So that each filter is its own component, able to be inserted into any array of products anywhere? Like how can a React component also provide its own logic/functions that other components can use (product array in, filtered product array + JSX UI out, but chainable).

Is that even the right way to think about this problem...? I'm confused about how to best build this architecturally.

Comment: `filter` returns an array, so you can chain any additional array functions, like another `filter`, and then ultimately a `map` to map the resultant filtered data array to JSX. I could imagine using a `reduce` function on the data using an array of filter functions would possible to make the code a little more DRY and reusable.

Comment: That works from an array manipulation standpoint, but it doesn't really allow the filter logic and UI to be modularized into separate components. e.g. to add multiple filters in a row, you'd have to write the filter logic separately in the render loop and then add the JSX for the UI and manually tie that into the logic. Is there no way to make a "pipeline" of JSX with UI + logic?

Comment: You could hold a filter (object with all criterias) in your parent component and then provide the setter to the "filter child components" (e.g. `<NameFilter  onChange={(newFilterItem) => setFilter((oldFilter) => ({...oldFilter, yourCriteria: newFilterItem.yourCriteria  || null   }))  }  />`). Let me know if I should describe an answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to this question

> What's the most "React"y way to build reusable, chainable filter
> components?

I suggest separate display & data logic by using hooks. Move all data related logic into a hook, and import that hook to a react component.

```
// useProducts.js
const useProducts = () => {
  const [products, setProducts = useState([]);
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({}); // eg. filters = { size: 'large', availability: 'instock' }

  // Get all products on initial load
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(....).then(response => setProducts(response.data));
  }, []);

  // function to set filter.
  const setFilter = (name, value) => {
    setFilters({ ...filters, [name]: value });
  }

  // Loop filters and filter product 
  const filteredProducts = [...products];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filters)) {
    // Get list of products from somewhere.
    filteredProducts = filterProducts.filter(p => p[key] === value);
  }

  return [filteredProducts, { setFilter }];
}

// Product List
import React from 'react';
import useProducts from './useProducts';

const ProductList = (props) => {
  const [products, { setFilter }] = useProducts();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="toolbar">
        <NameFilter onChange={value => setFilter('name', value)} />
        <SizeFilter onChange={value => setFilter('size', value)} />
        <AvailabilityFilter onChange={value => setFilter('availability', value)} />
      </div>
      <div>
        {products.map(p => <ProductItem {...p} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Additionally, you can even modularize it more by import { setFilter } in the filter component itself. And you can remove the 'onChange' from the ProductList.

```
const NameFilter = () => {
  const [, { setFilter }] = useProducts();
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={e => setFilter('name', e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}


// And now, we can remove onChange from each filter in Product List component
<div>
  <div className="toolbar">
    <NameFilter />
    <SizeFilter />
    <AvailabilityFilter />
  </div>
  <div>
    {products.map(p => <ProductItem {...p} />}
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note: Above code is just psuedo, it just shows the idea.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to experiment with this to fully understand what it's doing (like how it's passing a set function to another hook), but I think this get it 95% of the way there!

If I wanted to make different variants of ProductList (like ProductGrid, ProductCards, ProductMosaic, etc.), I'd just import the useProducts in those other components and reuse the logic, right?

Comment: I should note that, with above code, each useProducts stores separate set of "products" (because each useProducts has its own "products" state. That should be fine for some use cases, but if it starts to become a problem having duplication of data, you'll need to add useContext into the mix and store "products" in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

Any issues with conditionally filtering?

```
const searchResults =(text, size) => {
    let filteredProducts = eventsFromAPI; // array of products as input

    filteredProducts = text ? filteredEvents.filter(product => fullTextFilter(text)) : filteredProducts;
    filteredProducts = size ? filteredEvents.filter(product => sizeFilter(product)) : filteredProducts
    filteredProducts = filteredEvents.filter(product => availabilityFilter(product));

    return filteredProducts;
};
```

size can be boolean.

can also be ... (psuedo code)

```
const Search =({filter = []}) => { 
    let filteredProducts = eventsFromAPI; // array of products as input

    filteredProducts = filter.indexOf('something') > -1  ? filteredEvents.filter(product => fullTextFilter(text)) : filteredProducts;
    filteredProducts = filter.indexOf('size') > -1 ? filteredEvents.filter(product => sizeFilter(product)) : filteredProducts
    filteredProducts = filteredEvents.filter(product => availabilityFilter(product));

    return filteredProducts; 
};
```

then u can call `search({ filter: ['size', 'availability']})` or if you made it in to an component then `<Search filter={['size', 'availability']} products={products} />`

or even

```
const Search = ({ size = null, text = '', availability = true}) => {
   ... conditionally filtering

   return //whatever product u render
}
```

Comment: I think the hard part is passing state back and forth between a UI component (`<NameFilter/>`) and the filter functions (`fullTextFilter()`).